# importrange not loading dynamic data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have two separate google sheets documents: one of them is a public document that only has the `IMPORTRANGE` that imports a bunch of rows and columns from a private document.

the problem is that the private doc has some custom app script functions and when I import the data to the public document it does not load dynamic data properly UNLESS the private doc is open on my computer.

so for example:

- if the private doc is open on my computer
- I open the public doc from the sheets app on my phone(diff google account)
- the data loads properly everything works

BUT

- if the private doc is closed on my computer
- and I open the public doc on my phone again the data from the custom functions is gone

how im using the formula:
`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id","A1:J64")`

Is there a solution to this? is there a way to make importrange open the other google sheet in the server so it can run the script? I could not find anything in the docs

Comment: Maybe if you import the raw data without the calculations and run them from script in your public sheet? Maybe with some onOpen or onEdit trigger if you need the script to run from your cell phone

Comment: instead of ```IMPORTRANGE()``` function, how about add an ```installable trigger``` to your private doc, and set it to push new data to the public sheet on-private-doc-edit.